# Splitting a Long String Into Multiple Lines using javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string:

> The water content is considered acceptable for this voltage class. Dielectric Breakdown Voltage is unacceptable for transformers > 288 KV. Power factors, Interfacial Tension and Neutralization Number are acceptable for continued use in-service.".

I want to split the string into lines so that every line will contain at max 5 words in each line.

I want to control the number of words in each line dynamically, so that tomorrow I will be able to split the string into lines where each line contain at max N sentences in each line.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I will upload the code right away.

Comment: Do you *really* mean sentences, or did you mean words? Your example doesnt even contain 3 sentences.

Comment: I mean words , my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var string="The water content is considered acceptable for this voltage class. Dielectric Breakdown Voltage is unacceptable for transformers > 288 KV. Power factors, Interfacial Tension and Neutralization Number are acceptable for continued use in-service.";

var yourSplit=function(N,string){
  var app=string.split(' '),
      arrayApp=[],
      stringApp="";
  app.forEach(function(sentence,index){
    stringApp+=sentence+' ';
    
    if((index+1)%N===0){
      arrayApp.push(stringApp);
      stringApp='';
    }else if(app.length===index+1 && stringApp!==''){
      arrayApp.push(stringApp);
      stringApp='';
    }
  });
  return arrayApp;
  
};
console.log(yourSplit(5,string));
console.log(yourSplit(3,string));
console.log(yourSplit(8,string));
```